# how to disable onclick function once it is less than another variable?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Hello everyone and thanks for any help in advance,

I have some functions already in place, first one adds 1% of the total money amount once every second. the second is onclick there is $100 added to the total original amount. The third is to minus $200 plus 10% of the 200 from the total amount, so every time it is clicked the minus amount goes up. 
These functions are working on my local machine but I am unable to get them to work in a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/twwhhn71/4/)**.

I want to disable the minus button once the total amount is less than the minus amount, and also enable it again once there is enough money in the total amount to use.

Here is my JS so far

```
setInterval(function () {
    var moneyTotal = document.getElementById('money-total').innerHTML;
    var perSec = (1 / 100) * moneyTotal;
    var moneyNewTotal = (+moneyTotal) + (+perSec);
    document.getElementById('money-total').innerHTML = (moneyNewTotal.toFixed(2));
    document.getElementById('per-second').innerHTML = (perSec.toFixed(2));
}, 1000);

function add() {
    var addAmount = 100;
    var moneyTotal = document.getElementById('money-total').innerHTML;
    var addTotal = (+addAmount) + (+moneyTotal);
    document.getElementById('money-total').innerHTML = (addTotal.toFixed(2));
}

function minus() {
    var cost = document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML;
    var money = document.getElementById('money-total').innerHTML;
    if (money > cost) {
        var moneyNewTotal = (+money) - (+cost);
        var newCost = (10 / 100) * cost;
        var costTotal = (+newCost) + (+cost);
        document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML = Math.ceil(costTotal);
        document.getElementById('money-total').innerHTML = (moneyNewTotal.toFixed(2));
    } else {
        alert("Not enough money");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why not put a condition inside the minus function which only applies the new value if (minus >= total) that way you aren't enabling/disabling events

Comment: I have tired that but it will give off false trues and I can't figure out why. see my updated code for my attempt to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the Fiddle isn't working because you have it set to load your javascript `onLoad` which is wrapping your functions in a different scope and so they aren't available on the window. Changing it to load the javascript `No wrap - in <head>` (or `<body>`) will help it work.

Then you need to have something that is checking for the value and enabling disabling the minus button.

```
function checkTotal() {
    var moneyTotal = +document.getElementById('money-total').innerHTML; 
    var cost = +document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML;
    if (cost > moneyTotal) {
        document.getElementById('minus').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');    
    } else {
        document.getElementById('minus').removeAttribute('disabled');    
    }
}
```

Then you would need to call this at the end of the `add`, `minus`, and even the function you have defined in `setInterval` so that as money gets added it checks. This code only adds the `disabled` attribute to the button, so any styling would need to be handled either by the code or through CSS and setting/removing class names or something similar.

There are perhaps different ways to do this through data binding or using an event model as part of a framework, but those are a more substantial topic that can't really be covered in this answer.

Comment: Wow, so exactly what does adding + before document.getElementById('money-total').innerHTML do? That fixed my random results.

Comment: normally I would suggest using `parseInt` but since you were using that pattern already I stuck with it - Essentially it causes the code to cast the value of `innerHTML` to a `Number` since it is a `String` otherwise.

Comment: Yes makes sense, Thank you for you help I was stuck on that part and now I am gold. Thanks!